# Deletion of a single node in xml using c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

My xml file is as follows:

```
   <Default>
      <CareSettingName>
         <Name>Hosp1/Name>
         <Name>Hosp2/Name>
         <Name>Hosp3/Name>
         <Name>Hosp4/Name>
       </CareSettingName>
      <DocNames>
         <Name>Doc1/Name> 
         <Name>Doc2/Name> 
         <Name>Doc3/Name> 
        </DocNames>
    </Default>
```

With the following code I try to delete Hosp4:

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.Load(localXMLfile);
 XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Default/CareSettingName[Name='Hosp4']");

 node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
 xmlDoc.Save(localXMLfile);
```

When I run this, it deletes ALL the entries in CareSettingName - not the single one I am looking for. I can't see to find the problem. Can somebody please help me?

Can anybody please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're selecting `/Default/CareSettingName` (when it contains a `Name` that equals `Hosp4`).

Try changing your xpath to:

```
/Default/CareSettingName/Name[.='Hosp4']
```

Comment: @user2058253 - You're very welcome. Can you please accept this answer by checking the check mark next to it? Thanks!